# How to block my cpanel link for the users who are accessing my website.

Tags: htaccess, links, cpanel

I want to block my cpanel link i.e www.example.in/cpanel for the users who are trying to access it, but it should be accessible only for me. Is there anyway to block it. I don't know anything about it. Any help will be appreciated. I don't know this question is valid for this Stack Exchange Community.

Comment: Presumably you are on a shared server? Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: I am on a shared server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a shared server (with no access to the server config) then I don't believe this is possible unfortunately.

I don't know exactly how cPanel implements the `/cpanel` "redirect", but I imagine it's possibly an `Alias` in the server config. It doesn't map to a resource within your webspace. You can't override an `Alias` in the Apache `.htaccess` file within your site.

Trying to "block" access to the URL `/cpanel` in `.htaccess` simply has no effect.

Comment: Is it possible to block cpanel link by using .htaccess if i don't have the access to server config

Comment: Sorry if my answer was not clear... No, I do not believe this is possible using `.htaccess`. Any request for `/cpanel` doesn't even reach your webspace, it's _redirected_ (in some way) at the server level. If you check your site's access log, then I doubt you will see any entries for these requests.

Comment: How to check log

Comment: Do i have to purchase another plan from hosting provider or how to access server config, I don't know anything about server config

Comment: Any answer for this

Comment: If you are on a shared server then you can't access the "server config". You'll need to contact your host. However, if you want to control access to your cPanel login then you'll likely need to move away from a shared server environment (but this will also require you knowing a lot more about the "server config").

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted to remove it from the unanswered question queue, and upvote if you found it useful. Much appreciated, thanks. :)

Comment: Thank for your reply, someone suggested me to add the below code in .htaccess to block cpanel link

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 #301 redirect #first option throw them on home page 
 redirect 301 /cpanel/ /
 redirect 301 /cpanel/ /your404urlpage
</IfModule>

I had added but the link of cpanel is still working, what is your opinion regarding this code

Comment: Yes, that code won't work. As I stated in my answer, "Trying to "block" access to the URL `/cpanel` in `.htaccess` simply has no effect." (Btw, that code doesn't strictly "block", it "redirects" by sending a 301 response - which is not the recommended way of doing this anyway.)

Comment: So access server config what changes i have to do in my hosting plan

Comment: As I stated above, "you'll need to contact your host" in order to discuss the possibilities.

Comment: Okzz thank you @DocRoot you are excellent in conversation.